# F# - splitting list of integers into odds and evens using List.foldBack

Tags: list, f#

I'm trying to write a function using `List.foldBack` that'll split a list of integers into a tuple containing two lists: One containing the odds and the other the evens of the original list. Example:

Given the list `myList = [1;4;2;6;5;3;10]`, the function should return the tuple `([4;2;6;10], [1;5;3])`.

I have found plenty of solutions for splitting lists into sublists by their indices, however as explained I need to split the list by element value, not index.

So I figured I would write a function using `List.foldBack` that would split by index and then rewrite it to split by value, but have yet to be successful ... here is what I've arrived at so far:

```
let oddEvenSplit (listToSplit:int list) =
    List.foldBack (fun x (even, odd) -> x::odd, even) listToSplit ([], [])
```

As you might've guessed, running `myList` through my function returns `([1;2;5;10], [4;6;3])`.

I am restricted to using `List.`-`fold`, `foldBack`, `find`, `filter`, `map`, and `map2`, but would prefer to see a solution using only `foldBack`, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually check whether the value is odd or even – it just adds it to the 'odds' list regardless, and swaps the 'odds' and 'evens' lists for each value. Fixing both is straightforward, if ugly:

```
let oddEvenSplit listToSplit =
    List.foldBack
        (fun x (even, odd) -> if x % 2 = 0 then (x::even, odd) else (even, x::odd))
        listToSplit
        ([], [])
```

How to make things less ugly is subjective, but here are a couple of options:

```
let oddEvenSplit listToSplit =
    let impl x (even, odd) = if x % 2 = 0 then (x::even, odd) else (even, x::odd)
    List.foldBack impl listToSplit ([], [])

// or

let oddEvenSplit listToSplit =
    (listToSplit, ([], [])) ||> List.foldBack (fun x (even, odd) ->
        if x % 2 = 0 then (x::even, odd) else (even, x::odd))
```

Personally, I recommend the latter as it plays better with type inference in general (it made no difference here since `int` could be inferred regardless due to use of `%`).

Comment: Thank you so very much! I don't think the first solution is at all ugly. But perhaps this is because F# is still very new to me, and that's the one out of the three solutions you proposed that fit best into my current understanding of the language. Much appreciated!!